# function pointer in c++ class throws compiler error

Tags: c++

I am new to function pointer and tried to pass the function pointer as parameter from one class to other and getting compiler error.

> 'fncptr1': is not a class or namespace name"

what am I doing wrong?

**fncptr1.h**

```
#ifndef FNCPTR1
#define FNCPTR1

#include "fncptr2.h"
class fncptr1
{
  public:
    int addition(int a,int b);
    void testfncptr();  
};

#endif // !FNCPTR1
```

**fncptr1.cpp**

```
 #include "fncptr1.h"
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int fncptr1::addition(int a,int b)
 {
   return a + b;
 }

 void fncptr1::testfncptr()
 {
    fncptr2 f;
    f.implfncptr(&addition);
 }
```

**fncptr2.h**

```
 #ifndef FNCPTR2
 #define FNCPTR2

 #include "fncptr1.h"
 class fncptr2
 {
   public:
      int implfncptr(int (fncptr1::*add)(int,int));
 };

 #endif // !FNCPTR2
```

**fncptr2.cpp**

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "fncptr2.h"
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;
  fncptr1 ff;

  int fncptr2::implfncptr(int (fncptr1::*add)(int, int))
  {
    return (ff.*add)(1,2);
  }
```

**main.cpp**

```
fncptr1 f;
f.testfncptr();
```

Comment: `fncptr1.h` includes `fncptr2.h` and `fncptr2.h` includes `fncptr1.h`, this is seriously wrong.

Comment: And `f.implfncptr(&addition);` should be `f.implfncptr(&fncptr1::addition);`

Comment: @Jabberwocky: please assist how to remodify the code

Comment: Also show `main.cpp`, the one you show is incomplete, and show the full error log.

Comment: It's also unclear what you're hoping for when calling `f.testfncptr();` in `main`. The result of the addition is just thrown away.

Comment: Just remove `#include "fncptr2.h"` from `fncptr1.h`, there is no need to include that there. Instead include it in the source file, because there you actually use classes from that header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove the includes of `fncptr2.h` and `fncptr1.h` from all .h files. Instead add them to `fncptr1.c` and `fncptr2.c`.
- you need `f.implfncptr(&fncptr1::addition);` instead of `f.implfncptr(&addition);` in `fncptr1.cpp`

**fncptr1.h**

```
#ifndef FNCPTR1
#define FNCPTR1

class fncptr1
{
public:
  int addition(int a, int b);
  void testfncptr();
};

#endif // !FNCPTR1
```

**fncptr2.h**

```
#ifndef FNCPTR2
#define FNCPTR2

class fncptr1;

class fncptr2
{
public:
  int implfncptr(int (fncptr1::* add)(int, int));
};

#endif // !FNCPTR2
```

**fncptr1.cpp**

```
#include "fncptr1.h"
#include "fncptr2.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fncptr1::addition(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}

void fncptr1::testfncptr()
{
  fncptr2 f;
  f.implfncptr(&fncptr1::addition);
}
```

**fncptr2.cpp**

```
#include "fncptr2.h"
#include "fncptr1.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
fncptr1 ff;

int fncptr2::implfncptr(int (fncptr1::* add)(int, int))
{
  return (ff.*add)(1, 2);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "fncptr1.h"

int main()
{
  fncptr1 f;
  f.testfncptr();
}
```